# Is there a way to figure out the type of object (in array of bytes form) C++?

Tags: c++, object, pointers, boost, boost-asio

I have been using boost::asio for a client server application, I am sending packed structs to and fro as messages, the server need to identify the the type of request struct passed to it and accordingly determine the response for it. For now each struct has a unique `TemplateId`, which is stored in a second level struct: `MessageHeader`, is there a way to know the type of struct from the byte array received ( char *) .

**sample struct:**

```
typedef struct { 
    MessageHeaderInComp MessageHeaderIn;
    RequestHeaderComp RequestHeader;
    uint32_t Username;
    char Pad4[LEN_PAD4];
} __attribute__((packed)) UserLogoutRequest;



typedef struct { 
    uint32_t BodyLen;
    uint16_t TemplateID;  //this is unique
    char NetworkMsgID[LEN_NETWORKMSGID];
    char Pad2[LEN_PAD2];
} __attribute__((packed)) MessageHeaderInComp;
```

for now I am using:

```
const UserLogoutRequest*obj = reinterpret_cast<const UserLogoutRequest*>(buf);  //buff is a character array
int tempId = obj->MessageHeaderIn.TemplateID;
```

But this is hardcoded for a particular type (UserLogoutRequest), I want to replace this, what should i do? Any ideas or suggestions are welcome.

Comment: you mean in the reinterpreting part ? I tried that but it doesn't work for some reason while decoding

Comment: can you be more specific than `doesn't work`? Please provide a [mre]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method will work if *all* responses have the same *initial* structure

```
typedef struct {
   uint32_t BodyLen;
   uint16_t TemplateID;  //this is unique
```

If *all* of the requests have that as beginning, it will work. No matter of the real type. You can cast any `char *` pointer to a `MessageHeaderInComp` type and verify the `TemplateID`.

In fact that method is used in lots of libraries and, depending on the type id, it can later be cast to the correct struct based on the id.

Comment: Worth mentioning trivial types and standard-layour